# Android : UUID of Custom Service of my BLE peripheral is not finding

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, android-ble, bluetooth-peripheral

One of My application is working as a Bluetooth peripheral, I add one Custom Service and 3 characteristics in it. My Client application after connected to peripheral discover its services, but UUID of my service is different in different clients. One of my Samsung devices returns UUID perfectly that I added while advertising my service, while another device shows different UUID. For now, I am checking characteristics inside service if service UUID doesn't match but surprisingly all the characteristics are inside this service.  But the service UUID is not what I added in my service.

**Here is my code that discovers services**

```
if(newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                isConnected =true;
                Log.i(BluetoothClientActivity.class.getSimpleName(),
                        "Connected to GATT server.");
                // Attempts to discover services after successful connection.
                Log.i(BluetoothClientActivity.class.getSimpleName(),
                        "Attempting to start service discovery:");
                gatt.discoverServices();

            }
```

**Sample code of adding Custom Service with three characteristics**

```
UUID PRIMARY_SERVICE = UUID.fromString("145d6dba-7064-11ea-bc55-0242ac130003");
    mSampleService = new BluetoothGattService(PRIMARY_SERVICE, BluetoothGattService.SERVICE_TYPE_PRIMARY);

    mSampleService.addCharacteristic(characteristic1);
    mSampleService.addCharacteristic(characteristic2);
    mSampleService.addCharacteristic(characteristic3);
```

is there any way to identify my service and characteristics inside that can be used for communication between server and client.

```
List<BluetoothGattService> services = gatt.getServices();
for(Service service:services){
      if(service.getUuid().toString().equals(SERVICE_UUID_STRING)){
         Log.e(TAG,"Found");
     }else{
        Log.e(TAG,"Not Found");
     }
}
```

Comment: Have you solved this ?